# Unable to connect the LibreOffice on port 2002?

Tags: docx, libreoffice, doc, libreoffice-base, docverter

I am using the docvert 5.1 for convert .doc to html.When i run the "Tests (run all)" during I am getting the error message under the following parts:

" ✘Unable to run tests due to exception.  Failed to connect to LibreOffice on port 2002. Connector : couldn't connect to socket (Success) If you don't have a server then read README for 'OPTIONAL LIBRARIES' to see how to set one up."

Footnotes
Heading and paragraphs
Images
Lists

I have found it from here : https://github.com/holloway/docvert/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have to start your server using this command :

```
sudo apt-get install libreoffice python-uno python-lxml python-imaging pdf2svg librsvg2-2

/usr/bin/soffice --headless --norestore --nologo --norestore --nofirststartwizard --accept="socket,port=2002;urp;"
```

(from https://github.com/holloway/docvert/blob/master/README.md)